# Accessing data in a nested dictionnary and return source of his data

Tags: python

We have several nested dictionary, an user can use these different nested dictionary to build a YAML file.
They are free to use a data from dictionnary "*data1*", and another data from dictionnary "*data2*"

But in the generated YAML, it's hard to know quickly the source of the data.

So, I would like to have the easiest way to access to a data and add the path to this data, for example :

```py
my_data_dict = {
    "data_source_1": {"foo": {"bar": 'data1'}},
    "data_source_2": {"foo": {"bar": 'data2'}},
    "data_source_3": {"foo": {"bar": 'data3'}},
}

>>> my_data_dict["data_source_1"]["foo"]["bar"]

expected : {'data': 'data1', '__source': '["data_source_1"]["foo"]["bar"]'}
```

For now, I use an ugly method based on "*eval*" :

```py
def get_info(_my_data_dict, keys):
    """Return data in a dictionary with 2 keys : data and __source."""
    result = dict()
    result["data"] = eval(_my_data_dict + keys)
    result["__source"] = str(keys.strip())
    return result

my_data_dict = {
    "data_source_1": {"foo": {"bar": 'data1'}},
    "data_source_2": {"foo": {"bar": 'data2'}},
    "data_source_3": {"foo": {"bar": 'data3'}},
}

>>> print(get_info("my_data_dict", '["data_source_1"]["foo"]["bar"]'))
{'data': 'data_foobar', '__source': '["data_source_1"]["foo"]["bar"]'}
```

But I think it's never a good idea to keep '*eval()*' in a production code :)

So is someone have an idea to doing something like that in a better and cleaner way ? Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

We can do it by parsing the keys string to a list form and iterating over keys by reassigning the result

```
from re import findall
my_data_dict = {
    "data_source_1": {"foo": {"bar": 'data1'}},
    "data_source_2": {"foo": {"bar": 'data2'}},
    "data_source_3": {"foo": {"bar": 'data3'}},
}
keys = '["data_source_1"]["foo"]["bar"]'

def get_info(my_data_dict, keys):
    path = findall(r'"(.+?)"', keys)  # converts {keys} to list
    data = my_data_dict
    for i in path:
        data = data.get(i)
    resp["data"] = data
    resp["__source"] = keys
    return resp

get_info(my_data_dict, keys)
```

Comment: Thanks for this other solution, i gonna to try something by converting the dictionnary into an object and try to use "__getitem__ etc..."